# How do I edit the Vim MOTD?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to edit the Vim MOTD?

> VIM - Vi IMproved
>
> version 7.3.390
>   by Bram Moolenaar et al.
>   Vim is open source and freely distributable
>
> Sponsor Vim development!
>   type :help sponsor`<Enter>` for information
>
> type :q`<Enter>` to exit
>   type :help`<Enter>` or `<F1>` for on-line help
>   type :help macvim`<Enter>` for MacVim help

I figure I've got all this down already and I'd like to personalize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just [browsing through](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/) the Vim source code, and found that indeed, the above text is hard-coded into [the `version.c file`](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/version.c).  You'll need to download the latest version of the source code, either from the Google Code repository linked above, or from your latest distribution's package repository.

Once you have the source code, go through the file outlined above to find the strings you want to replace.  There are several different cases in the file, but you should be able to simply find-and-replace most of it (just be careful not to modify the semantics of the source code, or you might have compilation issues!).  In particular, the message is printed in the `intro_message` function.

After the changes have been made, you should be able to just call `make` and then `make install` (from the base source code directory, the one with the `Makefile`) - and that should be it!

---

As an alternative method, depending on your OS/other limitations (signed binaries, etc...), you could use a hex editor on the binary to find-and-replace the strings you wanted directly in the compiled application.  However, you need to use caution, as you can only write over what's already there.  This implies that you cannot remove and add characters; you can, however, just use spaces to ignore some stuff...

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I'm assuming this means that if OS X updates Vim, I'll be redownloading and recompiling?

Comment: Yes; I also updated the answer with another method, which may be easier depending on your needs (and could be automated to be quick; although one could argue that the prior method [compiling from source] is just as fast, and if you're crafty, you could just clone the official Mercurial repo from the link in the answer.  Then, just update your Vim manually, but constantly download and merge in changes - makes it essentially automated, and you could craft up a pull-merge-build script really easily).

Comment: Absolutely wonderful; editing a few lines from `version.c`, then running `make` and `make install` worked perfectly, though now Powerline is confused as all hell ;) Thanks again, I'm going to enjoy playing around with this. I hope others find this as useful as I did (though I seem to be the only person to have Googled for this...)

Comment: Oops, nevermind about Powerline. (Couldn't edit the comment)